# What is the hash function used by MongoDB to hash the database user passwords?

Tags: security, mongodb, hash

In MongoDb use can add user to a database for access control. A user can be inserted with:

```
db.addUser({ user: "aaaa", pwd: "1234", roles: [...]})
```

and the inserted user is:

```
{
    "user" : "aaa",
    "pwd" : "08ccdf34dbb3ca05dcc195e30994b628",
    "roles" : [
        "userAdminAnyDatabase"
    ],
    "_id" : ObjectId("52a88b45965c4e7ad46bb97b")
}
```

What function does MongoDB use to compute/hash the `pwd` key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The pwd is the hex encoding of MD5( username + ":mongo:" + password_text ).

From the official [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/implement-authentication-in-driver/).

The result does not coincide with the hash you show in your json, but I think you replaced the actual username and password anyway as you add `"aaaa"` but retrieve `"aaa"`.

Comment: Thanks! And your assumption is correct. I did replace the user name. :)

Comment: When I tried MD5( username + ":mongo:" + password_text ) in mongo shell I got

`Error: MD5 string must have 32 characters`

Comment: +1 for the documentation link. It changed since then, but the documentation was updated so I found the answer there.